# Get "real" class of generic type

Tags: java, generics

How can I get the "real" class of a generic type?

For Example:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    public void method(){
        //something

        System.out.println(T.class) //causes a compile error, I wont the class name

        //something
    }
}
```

If T = Integer

Output:

```
java.lang.Integer
```

If T = String

Output:

```
java.lang.String
```

Thanks

Comment: You can get this through reflection. BUT... bear in mind if you have to treat your data differently depending on its generic type, you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't have to. If you do have to, it's not as generic as you think it is, and that means there's a problem in your class.

Comment: @glowcoder: One example where this might be valid, which I've run into myself, is accessing a static property of the generic type.  One workaround is defining an instance that you never really use, like `T obj;`, so you can say `obj.static_property` later on.  Also, you can do `((T)null).static_property`.

Comment: If you have an object of that type, you could call the `getClass` method on that object. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @glow: please post an answer so we can upvote it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a instance variable of type T in your class, and it happens to be set, then you could print the class of that variable.

```
public class Test<T> {

    T var;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> a = new Test<Integer>();
        System.out.println(a.boo());
        a.setVar(new Integer(10));
        System.out.println(a.boo());
    }

    public String boo() {
        if (var == null) {
            return "Don't know yet";
        }
        return var.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    public void setVar(T var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public T getVar() {
        return var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider the case where var is set to an instance of class X where X extends T. boo() will print X instead of T.

Answer (score 11):

You can't.  The information is stripped from the code at compile time, a process that is known as type erasure.  For more, please look here: [Type Erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure)

edit: sorry my bad, the information is not loaded at run time.

Comment: well, not specifically true, it's in the class file as class or method attributes. It's just not loaded into memory at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

As others have explained, you cannot do it in that fashion but this is how it's usually achieved in java.

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    public void method(Class<T> clazz) {
        // something

        System.out.println(clazz.getName());

        // something
    }
}
```

and you use it like this

```
new MyClass<String>().method(String.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of your situation, you can't. However, you might be able to use Super Type Tokens for this type of thing: http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

An example implementation of these is the TypeReference class of the Jackson json processing library.

This is advanced stuff and probably more than you wanted to know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that approaches relying on 'getClass()' on an instance received with a generic type will get the actual type of that object, which is not necessarily the generic type - which would be the type by which the caller knew the instance.

For example, consider the case where the caller handles an object by an interface; when passing to generic constructs, the generic type will be the interface, not the instance's actual class.

Consider the following example "Pair" class, which allows two object references to be returned through a POJO:

```
public class Pair<U,V>
{
    public final U first;
    public final V second;
    public static <U,V> Pair<U,V> of (U first, V second)
    {
        return new Pair<U,V> (first, second);
    }
    protected Pair (U first, V second)
    {
        this.first  = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

We were considering how to modify the 'Pair.of()' factory function to return a Comparable Pair derived class, if U and V were both Comparable.  However, while we can tell whether 'first' and 'second' are comparable using instanceof, we don't know that 'U' and 'V' are themselves comparable.

For this to work, the exact type of Pair returned by Pair.of() must depend on the generic types, *not* the actual argument types.